# Combining tables and figures with common subtitle

Tags: subfloats, minipage

I am trying to obtain the following:

Figure 1: Title

(A) Panel A subtitle

Figure on the left - Table on the right

(B) Panel B subtitle

Figure on the left - Table on the right

(C) Panel C subtitle

Figure on the left - Table on the right

I tried to get there using a mix of minipage and subfloat but I really struggle with the subtitles. I would like a single, centered, subtitle for each figure and its corresponding table. How can I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaption{Panel A subtitle}
    \label{fig:sub-a}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}ll@{}}
      \toprule
      Foo & Bar \\\midrule
      1 & 2 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{.5ex}
  \par
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaption{Panel B subtitle}
    \label{fig:sub-b}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}ll@{}}
      \toprule
      Foo & Bar \\\midrule
      1 & 2 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Title of Figure}
  \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer - that solves my problem.

Comment: This is great, but do you have an idea how it can be adapted such that TWO of the tables are next to the image? Now there is white space in the top right corner. Say I have another table to put there, how to do that? @Arash

Comment: @dopexxx - I suggest you have a look at the `floatrow` package which is pretty powerful for this kind of stuff and search this sx for it.  Otherwise, open up a new question.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want the subcaptions to show up in the list of figures, you can just format text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\medskip
\textbf{(A)} Panel A subtitle\par
\smallskip
\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}% align tops
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfil
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
yada yada yada\\
\hline
yada yada yada\\
yada yada yada
\end{tabular}\par
\medskip
\textbf{(B)} Panel B subtitle\par
\smallskip
\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\height}% align centers
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfil
\begin{tabular}{c}
yada yada yada\\
\hline
yada yada yada\\
yada yada yada
\end{tabular}\par
\medskip
\textbf{(C)} Panel C subtitle\par
\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}\hfil
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}% align bottoms
yada yada yada\\
\hline
yada yada yada\\
yada yada yada
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: text area figure]

Comment: This template is great. It solved my problem. Thank you.